# React: how to set variables in helper functions?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and am creating a function within a broader React component and want to put a value a will use multiple times within a var.

```
  userFriendlyDate = (selectedDate) => (
    let startMonth = this.dateUtil.translateMonthShort(selectedDate.getMonth())

    selectedDate
      ? [startMonth, selectedDate.getFullYear(),
       startMonth].join(' ')
      : ' '
  )
```

I have tried using `let`, `const` and `var` but I get an error each time (at the point where I am creating the var).

How can I create a re-usable var just within this helper function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update your function like this. Simply you have to add `{` instead of `(` and set `return` inside the function.

```
userFriendlyDate = (selectedDate) => {
    let startMonth = this.dateUtil.translateMonthShort(selectedDate.getMonth())

    return selectedDate
      ? [startMonth, selectedDate.getFullYear(),
       startMonth].join(' ')
      : ' '
  }
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks for you quick response. Can you please Vote Up to the answer so it will helpful to other developer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the error?  I suspect it might be because of your parens

```
userFriendlyDate = (selectedDate) => (
```

Try curly braces instead.

```
userFriendlyDate = (selectedDate) => {
```

The paren is for a multi-line return statement.  Inside the block (when you use `{`) you'll need to add a `return`